# TextView goes singleLine when setting text on runOnUiThread

Tags: android, textview, runnable

I have a TextView that i inflate in my activity. When i set text to this TextView its content is spread in multiple lines as this is the default behaviour.
e.g

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.location_details);

       // inflate the view
       descriptionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView );
       descriptionTextView.setText("This is a long text that should be multilined");
       ....
    }
```

when i use the same text inside a Runnable in a runOnUiThread the text goes single line by default. I have to call setSingleLine(false) to be multilined ...
e.g

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.location_details);

       // inflate the view
       descriptionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView );

       new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run() {
             ...
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               descriptionTextView.setText("This is a long text that should be multilined");
            }
             });
          });
    }
```

Why is this happening ?

**EDIT**
My layout file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:padding="6dp"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_dashboard"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#565A5D"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:src="@drawable/divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/metaDivider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/metaArticleImage" />

            <ImageView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/imageDivider"
                android:src="@drawable/divider"
                android:contentDescription="@string/metaDivider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#55595C" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" 
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mapButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mapBtn" 
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

       </LinearLayout>     

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout> 

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/metaLogo"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it has to do with your layout constraints.  The reason you are seeing a difference is because in one case (called directly from `onCreate()`) the text is set **before** the views are laid out, so the `TextView` height is set to match the content inside.  In the second case (from the `Thread`), the text is set **after** layout is complete, and `TextView` does not adjust its size to match new content unless its `LayoutParams` explicitly tell it to do so.

If you set the `layout_height` attribute of your `descriptionTextView` to `wrap_content`, the resizing problem will go away.

HTH

Comment: thanks, that worked! I thought 0dp and wrap_content was exactly the same, since eclipse adviced me to change to 0dp "Use a layout_height of 0dip instead of wrap_content for better performance"

Comment: Eclipse made that suggestion because you had a `layout_weight` parameter applied to the view.  Since your goal is to have the view wrap the text contents, I'm not sure if the `layout_weight` is even really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted your whole layout we could try to do some more debugging. [`TextView.setText()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,android.widget.TextView.BufferType,boolean,int%29) ends up notifying the parent container and apparently this behaves differently depending on when it is called.

BTW, by looking at your code I think you could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of the outer Thread

Comment: I have edited my question, and included the layout. Hope you can see something.